# How to detect the form is blank or not by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I've multiple forms in my page. Some form/fields are required(class name requiredForm) and some are not. There is a link at the last named "Next".By default "Next" is in gray background(deactivate color background). I want when people fill only the required fields/forms, the background of "Next" will be changed to Orange. If they don't fill up requirement fields/forms, the "Next" link will be as it is.Basically, there is a form including about 9-10 radio button and a form including about 14-15 checkboxs. I don't need people check/click all of this. I need if people click/or select just one, disable(grey) link turn to orange. So, it may be more flexible if I check, if the required form is blank, grey link is as it is. If the required form is not blank, grey button will turn to orange. I'm trying to write the function. But, I don't know jQuery well. That's why, I can't understand how jQuery understand when people fill up the form or not.

Here is the sample code How the form is exist in my page:

```
<div class="row">
   <form class="myForm requiredForm">
       <input type="radio" id="lb1" name="radio" />
       <input type="radio" id="lb2" name="radio2" />
       <input type="radio" id="lb2" name="radio3" />
   </form>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <p>many Texts</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <form class="myForm">
       <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
       <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
   </form>" 
</div>
<div class="row">
   <form class="myForm requiredForm">
       <input type="checkbox" />     
       <input type="checkbox" />
       <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="deactive">Next</a>
```

CSS:

```
.next {
   background: #fa9a37;   // orange link color
   color: #fff;
}
.deactive {
   background: #fafafa;  // grey link color
   color: #333;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


   $('.deactive').addClass('.next');  // if people fill up the required forms
   $('.deactive').removeClass('.next');  // if people don't fill up the required forms
}
```

Comment: i would recommend using a jQuery Validation Plugin like http://jqueryvalidation.org/, this will give you access to all kinds of feedback for the user as well as enabling/disabling the next button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add a `required` class to all field that are required.

and try this code

```
<div class="row">
   <form class="myForm requiredForm">
       <input type="radio"  class="required" id="lb1" name="radio" />
       <input type="radio"   class="required" class="required"  id="lb2" name="radio2" />
       <input type="radio"  class="required" id="lb2" name="radio3" />
   </form>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <p>many Texts</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <form class="myForm">
       <input type="text"  class="required" id="name" name="name" />
       <input type="text"  class="required" id="email" name="email" />
   </form> 
</div>
<div class="row">
   <form class="myForm requiredForm">
       <input  class="required" type="checkbox" />     
       <input  class="required" type="checkbox" />
       <input  class="required" type="checkbox" />
</div>
<a href="#" id="next_link" class="deactive">Next</a>
```

/* define variable to each, at lease one selected element like checkbox and radio button */
    var is_radio_checked = false;
    var is_checkbox_checked = false;
    var is_other_required_field = true;

```
$('.required').each(function(){
   var type = $(this).attr('type');
   if( (type == 'radio') && !is_radio_checked){
     is_radio_checked = $(this).is(':checked');
   } else if((type == 'checkbox') && !is_checkbox_checked){
     is_checkbox_checked = $(this).is(':checked');
   } else if( (type == 'text') && is_other_required_field){ 
     var txt_val = $(this).val();
     if(txt_val == ""){
       is_other_required_field = false;
     }
   }     
});

if(is_radio_checked && is_checkbox_checked && is_other_required_field){
  $("#next_link").removeClass('deactive').addClass('next');
}
```

please have a look on image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to listen to changes on the input elements:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var conditions = checkForConditions(); // this is where you check if the mandatory inputs are filled in
    if (conditions)
        $('.deactive').addClass('next');
    else
        $('.deactive').removeClass('next');
});
```

I've created a small example based on toggling here: http://jsfiddle.net/5c44z/

You had two major errors:

- `.addClass('.next')` should be `.addClass('next')` - no dot needed since we know it's a class
- in your CSS, the next class is defined before the deactive class so the deactive rules would always override the next rules... you can fix this either by changing order or by toggling classes (so you can't have both of them at the same time)

---

And the condition check function could be something like this, assuming you put a class `mandatory` to each mandatory field:

```
function checkForConditions() {
    var ret = true;
    $('.mandatory').each(function() {
        if ( !$(this).val() ) { 
            ret = false;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Here's an example with that (the first input field is mandatory): http://jsfiddle.net/5c44z/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can just put all of it under just one `form` tag, give the required fields a class, say `required` and then

```
  var allDone = true;
  $(".myForm input.required").each(function() {
     if($(this).val() === "") {
        allDone = false;
        return false;
     }
  });
  if (allDone)
    $('.deactive').addClass('next');
  else
    $('.deactive').removeClass('next');
```